# Plugin Jenkins to Capture html just before an error execution?

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Does anybody know how to capture the html/url before an error appear in the test case with Selenium Webdriver??
I need to know the previous URL, and I don't know how...
I use Jenkins to run my tests.

I need some shell command to take a screenshoot and save in some directory. 
How could be that shell code?

I've tried with: UI TEST CAPTURE Plugin
But it didn't work...it doesn't let me to configure it. I don't know why. (I show you in a picture)[image: UI TEST CAPTURE Plugin]

I've written the following to my test-case java file:

```
String actualTest = this.getClass().getName()+"."+testname.getMethodName();
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)FabricaWebDriver.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("target/screenshots/"+actualTest+".png"));
```

But it work only when a test is SUCCESS. 
I need it when a test is FAILED,...... and I'm not able to get it.

I've tried with these conditions I show you in an image, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why...
[image: string matches]

Answer (score 0):

With regard to capturing the URL, I presume your site directs you to a page such as www.yoursite.com/error.htm or something similar?

In which case, the only option you have is to store the URL before each Selenium action, which is a pain

C#:

```
var currentURL = Driver.Url;
```

Or, if you're referring to handling an exception, you'd just capture the URL in the catch block.

Comment: My site doesn't direct me to an error.html, only I want to capture a screenshoot to watch the current page in which my test fails. Do I explain myself? thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Done! with this:

```
             try{
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("xxxxx")).click();
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         takeScreenshot(driver,e);
     }
     finally {
         driver.close();
    }
```

It works!